# Capturing an API response and uploading it to Drive

Tags: ajax, http, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a web app built with Google Apps Script that uses an external API service to convert the html page into a neat PDF file which is downloaded to the user's local machine - no problems there.

Now I need to take that response (the PDF file) and upload it to a specific folder on Drive using the drive folder ID.

My problem is trying to capture that API response object.  I've done this in a separate web app using a different html-to-pdf API and it works, so I know the majority of my code is sound.  But I am not properly capturing that object.  Maybe there is a Google Apps Script method to make this easier, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Strangely, documentation for running the Drive API in Google Apps Script is nonexistent.

*Please for the love of gawd, help a coder out!*

**

### Code.gs

**

```
/**
 * Special function that handles HTTP GET requests to the published web app.
 * @return {HtmlOutput} The HTML page to be served.
 */
function doGet(e) {
    var requestedId = e.parameter.zoho_id;
    var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Allied-po');
    templ.data = requestRecordFromCRM(requestedId);
    return templ.evaluate()
        .setTitle('Purchase Order')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

/* Upload PDF to specified Google Drive Folder */
function doSomethingForTheLoveOfGawd(strString){
   var obj = JSON.parse(strString)
   strDataURI=obj.str.replace("data:application/pdf;base64,", ""); 

   var str = Utilities.base64Decode(strDataURI); 
   var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(str).setContentType('application/pdf').setName("Purchase-Order.pdf");
   var file =  DriveApp.createFile(fileBlob) 
   DriveApp.getFolderById(obj.id).createFile(fileBlob)
   //hard-coded drive id# example:
   //    DriveApp.getFolderById('1pT_92oTwT0IKJi2WhhGfLHOgb-nZdaET').createFile(fileBlob)
}

/*Fetch Drive Folder ID from Zoho CRM API*/
function requestRecordFromCRM(requestedId) {
    //var requestedId = '392848000035649133';
    var authToken = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    var zohoRequestUrl = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/getRecordById?&authtoken=' + authToken + '&scope=crmapi&id=' + requestedId;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(zohoRequestUrl);
    var sanitizedResponse = (response.getContentText());
    var output = JSON.parse(sanitizedResponse);
    Logger.log(output);
    var parsedOutput = output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL;
    var recordObj = {}

    /*Assign Drive folder id to a variable*/
    for (var i = 0; i < output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL.length; i++) {
      Logger.log(output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL[i].val+" ==== "+output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL[i].content);
      var fl=output.response.result.Potentials.row.FL[i];
      if (fl.val == 'Drive Folder ID') {recordObj.driveFolderId = fl.content;}
    }
  return (recordObj);
}

function fixinput(input) {  
  Logger.log(input);
  return input;
}
```

**

### Javascript.html

**

```
<!-- jQuery, jQuery UI, and Bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Load Gdrive resource to save to record drive -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

<script>
//API Call - Convert HTML to PDF file and stores on local machine
    function call() {
        urltoconvert = "https://pdflayer.com/documentation";
        authkey = "XXXXXX";
        html1 = document.getElementById("printPage").innerHTML;
        url = "http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert" +
            "?access_key=" + authkey +
            "&document_name=Purchase_Order.pdf" +
            "&page_size=A4" +
            "&css_url=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.fortlauderdaletech.org/postyles.css";
        paramkey = "document_html";
        submitpost(url, "post", paramkey, html1);

        doc = //the object/PDF file returned by pdflayer API;
        doc.save('allied-po-demo.pdf');
        var blob = doc.output('datauri');
        var obj = { id: driveFolderId, str:blob };
        google.script.run.doSomethingForTheLoveOfGawd(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }

    function myajax(url, success1, fail1) {
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                success1(this.responseText);
            } else {
                alert(this.readyState + "," + this.status);
                fail1(url);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xhttp.send();
    }

    function submitpost(path, method, paramkey, htmlcontent) {
        method = method || "post";

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", paramkey);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", htmlcontent);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }

function ajaxposttest(success1,fail1) {

    authkey = "XXXXXX";

    html1 = document.getElementById("printPage").innerHTML;
    url = "http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert" ;

    paramkey = "document_html";
    //  alert(html1);
    var xhttp;
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //  console.log("responsetextajax="+this.responseText);
            success1(this.responseText);
        } else {
            alert("readystate="+this.readyState + ",status=" + this.status+",resptext="+this.responsetext);
            fail1(url);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("get", url, true);

    params=encodeURI("?access_key=" + authkey +
        "?access_key=" + authkey +
        "&document_name=Purchase_Order.pdf" +
        "&page_size=A4" +
        "&css_url=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.fortlauderdaletech.org/postyles.css&"+
        paramkey+"="+html1
        );

   //Send proper header info with request
   alert(params);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhttp.send(params);
   alert("2");
}

    function myajaxpost(url, params, success1, fail1) {
        var xhttp;
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                success1(this.responseText);
            } else {
                alert(this.readyState + "," + this.status);
                fail1(url);
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", url, true);

        //Send proper header info with request
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(params);
    }

    function succ(resp) {
        var pdfWin = window.open("" + resp, '', 'height=650,width=840');
    }

    function fail(resp) {}
</script>
```

**

### Allied-po.html

**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_blank">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Convert and Save to Drive</title>
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Stylesheet').getContent(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="printPage">
            <!-- Page 1 -->
            <section class="container">
                <section class="content">
                    <section class="post">
                        <div id="page1">
                            <section class="page1">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                      <form>
                                          <h3>Allied Contact</h3>
                                          <label>Drive Id Number</label>
                                          <input value="<?= data.driveFolderId ?>">
                                      </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </section>
                        </div>
                        <p id="page_number">- 1 -</p>
                    </section>
                </section>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center center-block">
            <button  class="btn btn-primary shadow hide-on-pdf" id="callbtn" onclick="call()" type="button">PDF Document  &#9996;</button>
            <p>Click to save as a PDF on your computer and send a copy<br/>
                to the Google Drive folder associated with this building.
            </p>
        <div>
        <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Javascript').getContent(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
<script>var driveFolderId="<?= data.driveFolderId ?>"</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of calling your Api from your Javascript (Client side) you use UrlFetch to do it on the server side like so

```
function convert(html) {
        var urltoconvert = "https://pdflayer.com/documentation";
        var authkey = "XXXXXX"; 
        var url = "http://api.pdflayer.com/api/convert" +
            "?access_key=" + authkey +
            "&document_name=Purchase_Order.pdf" +
            "&page_size=A4" +
            "&css_url=https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/www.fortlauderdaletech.org/postyles.css";
  var payload = {
    "document_html": html
  }
  var options = {
    "method" : "POST",
    payload : payload
  }
   var response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,options)
   doSomethingForTheLoveOfGawd(response)
   return JSON.stringify(response)

}
```

Then your can process your response to Drive File use your `doSomethingForTheLoveOfGawd` function

To download the file on the client side, you pass the response back to the client and use `.withSuccessHandler` to process the returned data

**Note** I am not sure of the structure of the response of the API so this is generic code. Modify as needed

```
function call() {

        var html1 = document.getElementById("printPage").innerHTML;
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showReturn).convert(html1);


    }

    function showReturn(data){
     var obj = JSON.parse(strString)
     var strDataURI= obj.blob /// points to the blob in the response. 
     var byteCharacters = window.atob(strDataURI)
     console.log(data)
     var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
     for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
       byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
     }
     var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
     var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: "application/pdf"});
     //console.log("running onload");
     var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     var a = document.getElementById("downLink");
     a.href = objectURL;
     a.download = "Purchase-Order.pdf"
     a.click();

    }
```